# What to consider when selecting RCA-to-3.5 mm cable for recordings

Tags: recording, cable, rca

I've got a Pioneer DJM800 (see [rear connections](http://www.pioneer-latin.com/downloads/djm-800_rear_hi.jpg)) mixer at home, and would like to record some mixtapes to my stationary computer that's 10 meters away. I'm considering getting a 10 metre RCA-to-3.5 mm cable and connect it to my computer. *(The computer's speakers will also work as monitors).*

Are there any considerations that I should note before making a purchase of cable? More specifically, I'm wondering:

- Will the 10 metre cable length have a detrimental effect on the quality of the recording?
- Should I consider getting gold- or silver-plated contacts?
- Anything else?

---

I should perhaps add that this is a relatively minor matter – I'm not super-serious about doing my recordings. With that said, I'd still like to make sure that the solution I'm getting is adequate.

I'm not considering any expensive upgrades, such as getting an external soundcard with XLR contacts and so forth, for this particular purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience is cables is that the length doesn't really matter as much as the quality of the cable. If the quality of the cable is problematic that will be a much greater source of sound degradation then changes in length.

That said, I'd still try to keep the run as short as possible...

If you're lucky enough to live in a country where some of your electronic's stores offer money back guarantees for change of mind try them. There may be a price premium (hopefully, not much) though depending on the store.

Unless you're an audiophile most people will be unlikely to notice the difference between gold and silver contacts. If you honestly want to 'hear the difference' go your local electrical department store. Look around the back of their television and sound gear to see whether you can 'hear the difference'.

If I were in your place, I'd be aiming for mid level gear as that will offer the best in terms of price versus performance ratio. I can't really tell the difference between that and the more high end stuff unless my surrounding environment is relatively quiet and the music is more 'sophisticated'.

Comment: To Me, Gold and silver or whatever type of contacts are more of a gimmick to allow a product to cost more. Ive tried and tried listening in such great details to both but its almost impossible to tell the difference. Dont worry about gold or silver, just get good quality cable.

Comment: @KeithC I'm not sure if the following is a "purchase recommendation question", and indeed it might have to be a new SE question – but how does one discern beforehand what a good cable is? Is it about knowing the right manufacturer?